# Convexity of Exponential Composite Function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

$f:\mathbb{R}_{+}^M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ is a convex analytic function. For $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^M$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$, consider the function $g:\mathbb{R}_{+}^{M+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ defined as

$g(\mathbf{x},y)=e^y[f(\mathbf{x})+c]$

where $c$ is a positive constant. I have a hunch that $g$ is a convex function but not able to prove it. Any hints, idea, or more importantly, counter example?

P. S. Forming the Hessian matrix for $g$ from that of $f$ is apparently a nice idea, but I am stuck to prove the final determinant will be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $g$ is not convex (everywhere).

For a counterexample, I pick $M = 1$, since that's easiest to write up, but of course a similar situation can arise in arbitrary dimensions. Let

$$f(x) = x^4 - \frac12 x + \frac{3}{16} + \varepsilon(x^2 + 1),$$

where $\varepsilon > 0$ is very small, it just serves to establish strict positivity and strict convexity and shall not interfere with the following. Let also $c > 0$ be sufficiently small. Then the Hessian (grr, that ought to be Hessean, the man was called Hesse) of $g$ is - modulo the factor $e^y$ -

$$\begin{pmatrix}
12x^2 + 2\varepsilon & 4x^3 -\frac12 + 2\varepsilon x\\
4x^3 -\frac12 + 2\varepsilon x & f(x)+c
\end{pmatrix}.$$

For $x = 0$, we obtain

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2\varepsilon & -\frac12\\
-\frac12 & \frac{3}{16} +\varepsilon + c
\end{pmatrix},$$

whose determinant is negative.

If $f$ is uniformly strictly convex (the smallest eigenvalue of the Hessian is strictly bounded away from zero), then choosing $c$ sufficiently large [if the values of $f$ are large enough, that is no constraint] guarantees convexity of $g$.

Comment: @Fischer Thanks a lot for your attempt. Actually the problem I am trying to solve (in the context of broadcast channel capacity) has a specific structure for $f(\mathbf{X})$ and then I need to know whether $g$ is convex or not. Additionally, I am interested in $\mathbf{X}\succ\mathbf{0}$. Now I feel that convexity of $g$ will depend on particular structure of $f(\mathbf{X})$, but not sure how to describe the structure to someone not belonging to the field of information theory.

Comment: Well, at least the example shows that you need some special knowledge about $f$ to show convexity of $g$. You can try to describe the structure of $f$ nevertheless, maybe that suffices for somebody to show the convexity of $g$ then. Without any knowledge about the special structure, it can't be done.

Comment: @Fisher Thanks. I made a different question concerning the same problem.